# trouble with labels in css. can't edit html

Tags: html, css

I need to align fields with their labels, all in 1 straight horizontal line. I'd normally fix this in the HTML, but I can't edit it, so I need it to be fixed with CSS.

This is the jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/83hxF/

My HTML:

```
  <label for="field_21770004">name</label>
  <input id="field_21770004" type="text" title="Please fill out this field." placeholder="" name="fields[21770004]"></input>
  <div id="field_21770004_errors" class="validation error"></div>
    <label for="field_21927140">depart</label>
    <select id="field_21927140" title="Please fill out this field." placeholder="" name="fields[21927140]"></select>
  <div id="field_21927140_errors" class="validation error" style="display: none;"></div>
    <label for="field_21769174">platform</label>
    <select id="field_21769174" title="Please fill out this field." placeholder="" name="fields[21769174]"></select>
  <div id="field_21769174_errors" class="validation error"></div>
```

My CSS:

```
#field_21770004 {
    width: 150px;
}

#field_21927140 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 250px;
}

#field_21769174 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 350px;
}
```

Comment: You want to align everything in one line ? with the field name and field input next to it ?

Comment: terrible HTML code, I wonder how some machine could generate such a terrible code?

Comment: I don't see any question but uhm: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: @Jonathan http://www.w3fools.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways that you can do that, have them aligned vertically or horizontally.

## 1st method:

HTML:

```
<label for="field_21770004">name</label>
<input id="field_21770004" type="text" title="Please fill out this field." placeholder="" name="fields[21770004]"></input>
<div id="field_21770004_errors" class="validation error"></div>
<label for="field_21927140">depart</label>
<select id="field_21927140" title="Please fill out this field." placeholder="" name="fields[21927140]"></select>
<div id="field_21927140_errors" class="validation error"></div>
<label for="field_21769174">platform</label>
<select id="field_21769174" title="Please fill out this field." placeholder="" name="fields[21769174]"></select>
<div id="field_21769174_errors" class="validation error"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#field_21770004 {
    width: 150px;
    display:inline;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/83hxF/4/

## 2nd method:

HTML:

```
<label for="field_21770004">name</label>
<input id="field_21770004" type="text" title="Please fill out this field." placeholder="" name="fields[21770004]"></input>
<div id="field_21770004_errors" class="validation error" style="display:none";></div>

<label for="field_21927140">depart</label>
<select id="field_21927140" title="Please fill out this field." placeholder="" name="fields[21927140]"></select>
<div id="field_21927140_errors" class="validation error" style="display:none";></div>

<label for="field_21769174">platform</label>
<select id="field_21769174" title="Please fill out this field." placeholder="" name="fields[21769174]"></select>
<div id="field_21769174_errors" class="validation error" style="display:none";></div>
```

CSS:

```
#field_21770004 {
    width: 150px;
}
#field_21927140 {
    top: 10px;
    left: 250px;
}
#field_21769174 {
    top: 10px;
    left: 350px;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/83hxF/5/

## 3rd method: (Changing CSS only)

```
#field_21770004 {
    width: 150px;
}
#field_21927140 {
    top: 10px;
    left: 250px;
}
#field_21769174 {
    top: 10px;
    left: 350px;
}

#field_21770004_errors{
    display:none;
}

#field_21769174_errors{
    display:none;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/83hxF/15/

Comment: The second method would work, but as I said. I can't edit the HTML as it is generated. Have to fix all positioning via CSS as the HTML.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: @shinyidol I have added a 3rd method with CSS change only. please let me know if that works for you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear to me what you mean. Align the labels where?

This is a solution that will align them **in a tabular way**, the label next to the input/select fields, each **in their own line**.)

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 6em;
}

.validation {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

(This assumes that the `display: none;` on the validation error field can be removed or altered. What is it there for in the first place? Can't this be done in the CSS file as well?)

Please try to explain a little better so I can be of better help.

Comment: have you tried this in some demo? I doubt it does nothing to the OP's problem, looks like he wants to align the labels in the same line with other fields. The problem is there is some `div` element which causes the line-break between the first label and the 2 remaining labels. There is no way to push them back on the same line except using absolute positioning.

Comment: I have tried it in his jsfiddle and it creates a display where the labels are aligned with the `input`/`select` fields. It's true they're not all on the same line, but then again, it's not really clear that was a requirement in the first place. I can add this fact to the answer text to make it obvious.

Comment: if so I think he doesn't need to do anything, just remove the absolute positioning of the last 2 fields like this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/83hxF/1/ BTW, I've just tried your code, it's of course not what the OP wants, the last 2 fields should have some label, but doing your way they don't have any associated  labels.

Comment: So why are you telling me this now? You could have posted it as a possible answer to the OP's question. I know he phrased it in a bad and unclear way, but we can try to help and narrow it down, can't we?

Answer (score 0):

Try floating the inputs/selects left and clearing right, and floating the labels left and clearing left.

```
input, select {
    float: left;
    clear: right;
}
label {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZHVpc/